# Search/Replace extract strings between elements

Tags: html, regex, xml, replace, atom-editor

I'm trying to extract all the url strings from a long xml file, the url I need is between loc elements and I want to discard everything else.

```
  <loc>https://www.website.com/1</loc>
```

So for example I would take this:

```
  <url>
   <loc>https://www.website.com/1</loc>
   <lastmod>2017-04-01T08:18:42+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>1.0000</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
   <loc>https://www.website.com/2</loc>
   <lastmod>2017-04-01T08:18:42+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>1.0000</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
   <loc>https://www.website.com/3</loc>
   <lastmod>2017-04-01T08:18:42+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>1.0000</priority>
  </url>
```

And return this:

```
https://www.website.com/1
https://www.website.com/2
https://www.website.com/3
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `<loc>(.+)<\/loc>` suffice? https://regex101.com/r/NWP4bQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = /https.*(?=<\/loc>)/gm;
str.match(regex)
```

This will return an array containing all the matches